# System module in rocketchip_wrapper.v

Tags: riscv

I was referring the rocketchip_wrapper.v in fpga-zynq/common/ to make certain modifications in it and customize it for a new fpga. On line 136, a module system is being interfaced (system system_i (.... )). Where is this system module defined?
Also, is the AXI module being imported from somewhere (ip core) or is it completely defined in the design itself?

Answer (score 0):

In Xilinx Vivado an instance of an IP cores (zynq processing system in your case) is represented by XCI files. The XCI file is an IP-XACT component instance XML file that records the values of project options, customization parameters, and port parameters used to create the IP ([UG895 Vivado System Level Design Entry](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2012_2/ug895-vivado-system-level-design-entry.pdf)).

Comment: If I want to use this on a different board (a non-Xilinx board), how can I go about doing that? Also, where can I find this XCI file?

Comment: For Altera you need to generate the processing system through QSys. This will generate a QIP file and a VHD/V file. The instantiation in VHDL/Verilog will be quite similar but with different port names.

The XCI files are generated through Vivado.

Answer (score 0):

The system module is defined within the Vivado project. It is how the rest of the IP blocks are exposed in verilog to the user's verilog and the block design is instantiated by a tcl script (e.g. zedboard/src/tcl/zedboard_bd.tcl). The AXI module is just another block in the block design for the project.

For using a non-Zynq board with rocket chip, I would look at the chisel code for the top level of rocket chip (RocketChip.scala) and look at the interfaces MemIO and HostIO. The verilog in rocketchip_wrapper.v is just a thin layer to convert those interfaces to the ones on the Zynq.